# hugepages not working with mariadb

Tags: mysql, centos6, galera, huge-pages

We tried to setup the hugepage for mariabdb running with galera cluster. We had allocated hugepages high enough to accommodate the innodb buffer.

### server.conf

```
[mysqld]
large-pages
innodb_buffer_pool_size =4G
```

### /etc/sysctl.conf

```
# hugepages information
vm.nr_hugepages = 3072

# Controls the maximum shared segment size, in bytes
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736

# Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
```

### /etc/security/limits.conf

```
@mysql      soft    memlock     unlimited
@mysql      hard    memlock     unlimited
```

free -m

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11908      11635        272          0         68       5502
-/+ buffers/cache:       6064       5843
Swap:         2559          0       2559
```

### Errors in mysqld.log

```
150403  4:46:12 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
InnoDB: HugeTLB: Warning: Failed to allocate 687865856 bytes. errno 1
InnoDB HugeTLB: Warning: Using conventional memory pool
150403  4:46:13 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

cat /proc/meminfo |grep -i huge

```
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       3072
HugePages_Free:        3072
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Comment: Tried the script at the bottom of this page to calculate your memory requirements?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/large-page-support.html

Comment: How much RAM do you have available?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen When i try the scrip i get (standard_in) 2: syntax error

Answer (score 1):

There is one step that I can see is missing in your configuration: you need to set the group number (of mysql) which can access the HugeTLB memory.

Check the currently assigned value:

```
$ sysctl vm.hugetlb_shm_group
```

This would probably only return 0, so the "root" group. You should either create a `hugetlb` group and add mysql to this group or use one of the groups mysql belongs too. Whichever group, use its GID (use respectively `grep '^hugetlb:' /etc/group | cut -d: -f3` or `id -g mysql`) and do:

```
# sysctl -w vm.hugetlb_shm_group=<gid>
```

(replace  by the GID of your group)

Test if it works, it it does add to /etc/sysctl.conf (or in a new file under /etc/sysctl.d/) the following line:

```
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = <gid>
```